# Visualisation Error in R

Tags: r, archlinux

I have been using R in Arch Linux for quite a while. But now the following snippets of code are giving the following errors-

```
D <- read.csv("some_file.csv", sep = ";")
View(D)
```

> Error in .External2(C_dataviewer, x, title) : unable to start data
>   viewer In addition: Warning message: In View(D) : unable to open
>   display

```
plot(D$Temperature ~ D$Hour)
```

> Error in .External2(C_X11, d$display, d$width, d$height, d$pointsize, 
>   :    unable to start device X11cairo In addition: Warning message: In
>   (function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  :
>   unable to open connection to X11 display ''

Why is this happening? Things were working fine before.
I am using R version 3.4.3 on x86_64 system.

On a terminal-

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

gives output-

> wayland-0

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have X11 running? Are you SSH'ed int a remote machine are are you running locally?

Comment: @MrFlick yes X11 is running since I am using GUI. No, its on my local system